# Clean up sharepoint URL

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

How do I stop SharePoint from adding unnecessary extension to the URL. See examples below:

1. mywebsite.com/Pages/Home.aspx
2. mywebsite.com/Athletics/Pages/default.aspx

**I want it to be something like below**

1. mywebsite.com
2. mywebsite.com/Athletics

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using SharePoint 2013. You can use managed navigation for friendly URLs.

Check this link for reference: [SharePoint 2013 – Friendly URLs and Managed Navigation](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/sharepoint-2013-friendly-urls-and-managed-navigation/)